# IntelliJ Show an Error on kotlinx.serialization, but compiling works

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a problem where IntelliJ tells me that the `@Serializable` annotation cannot be accessed as it's internal to kotlin.io etc. The `kotlinx.serialization` package also shows as an unresolved reference.

Apparently, this has something to do with using Kotlin 1.7.x as when I downgrade to Kotlin 1.6.10 the issue no longer presents itself. However, Gradle compiles and runs the application without issue even on 1.7.10. Therefore, this seems like ultimately an issue with IntelliJ and/or one of my settings.

This is a Kotlin Multiplatform project. I've tried many things to fix this:

- Reloading Gradle Project
- Refreshing Gradle Dependencies
- Completely refreshing all project indexes via the new `Repair IDE` tool
- Deleting .idea and .gradle folders
- Adjusting the project structure versions
- Generally messing around with versions and settings

My build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("multiplatform") version Versions.kotlin
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version Versions.kotlin
}

group = "com.example"
version = "4.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    js {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
            webpackTask {
                outputFileName = "app.js"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:${Versions.serialization}")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-html-builder:${Versions.ktor}")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cio:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-websockets:${Versions.ktor}")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-js:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:${Versions.ktor}")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:${Versions.ktor}")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react:${Versions.react}")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-dom:${Versions.react}")
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting
    }
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.app.ServerKt")
}

tasks.named<Copy>("jvmProcessResources") {
    val jsBrowserDistribution = tasks.named("jsBrowserDistribution")
    from(jsBrowserDistribution)
}

tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named<Jar>("jvmJar"))
    classpath(tasks.named<Jar>("jvmJar"))
}
```

```kotlin
object Versions {
    const val ktor = "2.0.3"
    const val kotlin = "1.7.10"
    const val coroutines = "1.6.3"
    const val serialization = "1.3.3"
    const val react = "18.2.0-pre.358-compat"
}
```

The class that is having issues is:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Customer(val id: Int, val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

[image: Serializable Error]
[image: serialization Package Error]

I appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Can you please report a bug to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KTIJ and attach a sample project to reproduce and your IDE logs?

Comment: I only just figured out yesterday that it is apparently caused by the MPP hierarchical structure that is enabled in Kotlin 1.6.20+ by default. Adding the flag `kotlin.mpp.hierarchicalStructureSupport=false` to gradle.properties does NOT work, but `kotlin.internal.mpp.hierarchicalStructureByDefault=false` does "fix" the problem.

Comment: Here is the issue that I eventually referenced for this info:
[Jetbrains Issue KTIJ 21638](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21638/MPP-IntelliJ-can-not-resolve-MPP-references-in-common-code?_ga=2.95903900.1668259612.1660084386-1891267789.1656619792&_gl=1*1rt78w7*_ga*MTg5MTI2Nzc4OS4xNjU2NjE5Nzky*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY2MDIzODAwOC4yNS4xLjE2NjAyMzgwNDkuMTk.)